# Update URL from Input control in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, http, url, input

when searched for oxy in search textbox  url is:
http://api.abc.com/GetGPs?**search=oxy**&uid=688-B65-462-F9-7A
and suppose I want to search for cor then url should change the moment I click on search button for cor. It should be like
http://api.abc.com/GetGPs?**search=cor**&uid=688-B65-462-F9-7A. The json file has same fields so display function in angular will work same as url will change and values too but not the type, name and the no. of fields

code is

```
  var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://api.abc.com/GetGPs?**search=oxy**&uid=688-B65-462-F9-7A
').success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.dta = data.emp;
    });
     $scope.reset = function () {
    $scope.enteredValue = '';
};
  });
```

//this is search texbox code

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="enteredValue" />
<button ng-click="reset()">Clear</button>
```

// this is filter that I am using

```
   <tr ng-repeat="x in dta | filter:enteredValue">
```

1) user input oxy .click search. url initially in http get http://api.abc.com/GetGPs?**search=oxy**&uid=688-B65-462-F9-7A
. search result displayed in angular

2) User Input cor.click search. URL should be updated itself to
http://api.abc.com/GetGPs?**search=cor**&uid=688-B65-462-F9-7A

3) display searched result in angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//.js

```
 countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.enteredValue = "*";
  $scope.targetUrl = 'url';
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.enteredValue = '';
  };
  $scope.doIt = function() {
    $scope.targetUrl = 'http://api.abc.com/GetGPs?search=' + $scope.enteredValue + '&uid=688-B65-462-F9-7A';
    $http.get( $scope.targetUrl )
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.dta = data.emp;
      });
  };
});
```

//html

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="enteredValue" />
  <button ng-click="doIt()">Submit</button>
  <button ng-click="reset()">Clear</button>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/6FJMnsA0rW54BLi6u5r7?p=preview plunker.... answer to the above problem by Matthew and its correct